# Why $W_{\rm net, out} = W_{\rm out} - W_{\rm in}$?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

Why when we use thermal efficiency the $\text{net work output} = W_{\text{out}}-W_{\text{in}}$ I asked my friend once he told me is that because we need the useful work but I told him an example in turbine heat engine Bryton cycle: isn't a turbine work out is the useful work while the compressor is not the useful work so why not just to take the $W_{\text{out}}$ why to take the $W_{\text{turb}}-W_{\text{comp}}$. Then he didn't answer me.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. The output may be $W_{out}$, sure, but if it requires some energy $W_{in}$ to produce this $W_{out}$, then naturally the **net** output is only the difference. Meaning, if you spend 10 J to produce 10 J, then you have not really produced anything. You may have converted between energy forms or you may have transported energy to somewhere else or something like that, but you haven't contributed with any energy generation overall.

Comment: Understood Steeven , thanks for your wise answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we talk about thermal efficiency we are talking about the efficiency of
the heat engine ***cycle*** to produce net work output and not the efficiency of the individual components (turbine, pump) by themselves.

That said, it doesn't mean the pump work is not "useful" work. Without it you would not be able to obtain necessary high pressure for the cycle. What's more, the efficiency of the pump is important since a less efficient pump will require a higher energy input to perform the the same work to obtain the necessary high pressure, thus reducing the net output of the cycle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Always helpful Bob , and always wise answers from you . REALLY THANKS.

Comment: You're welcome. So does that mean my answer is acceptable to you (since you didn't accept it)?

Comment: Hahaha sorry Bob. I missed about that. It is acceptable. I did accept it now. And thanks again bro.

Comment: You are very welcome